# .NET Core WCF Capture Soap Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core

In .NET Framework I could capture `SoapException` like below. This would allow me to read the Exception XML.

```
        try
        {
            // soap call here
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx)
        {
            var msg = soapEx.Message;
            var txt = soapEx.Detail.InnerText;
        }
```

In .NET Core, I'm generating the WSDL into code using `svcutil` and programatically building up endpoint and binding to call the client.

```
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endpointUrl);
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

        // call client passing endpoint and binding
```

Since I no longer have access to `SoapException` in .NET Core, how can I retrieve the Exception XML?

Comment: I would expect it to throw a [FaultException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultexception?view=netcore-2.0)

Comment: Thank you! This lead me in the direction I needed.